# How to correctly install and configure Cypress from behind a proxy?

Tags: angular, windows, cypress, npm-install

I have downloaded the Cypress zip file and unpacked it.
I then run this command to install with npm, from the e2e folder in an Angular project:

```
npm install /path_to_cypress_folder/cypress/Cypress/resources/app
```

and that returns
+ cypress@6.4.0
added 1 package in 0.057s

I have checked with a collegue that I am installing in the correct dir, and our folders appear the same in "e2e/node_modules".
But when I try to run tests I get an error:

```
> npx cypress open

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\meSelf\path\path\apps\pathweb\pathclient\e2e\node_modules\cypress\bin\cypress'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! e2e@1.0.0 cy:local: `npx cypress open`
```

I don't have a /bin/ folder in that location.
How can I resolve this error?

**Important info**: I am behind a proxy with ZERO internet access. I cannot download packages from the web, ie the cypress.zip file I have cannot be upgraded. $npm install WILL fail without a local path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation from a downloaded cypress.zip was done like this on Windows *without npm* (npm on thius system points to an internal repositiry):

1. Copy the zip to a permanent location on the drive, /C/Users/myUsr/myFolder
2. in gitbash: `$ CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=/C/Users/myUsr/myFolder/cypress.zip npm install cypress@6.5.0 --save-dev`
3. check the install works with `$ npx cypress verify` and when it times out:
4. change the cypress verify.js file to include `const VERIFY_TEST_RUNNER_TIMEOUT_MS = 130000;`

In step 2, I got the version number by unzipping the zip, and reading a json file (see criticism of cypress lack of naming convension below). For som e reason the install always was trying to install v.7.x even though it was not present on the system, or in the local repository that replaces npm on the web.

Also had a problem with Cypress not finding the cypress executable `cypress.exe` and it appears that all downloads from cypress website have the name `cypress.zip` and do NOT include a version number or platform in the zip's name. I think I had a wrong platform zip file, that did not include the executable for windows. Of course there was no way of knowing this wihout unzipping and searching for a file in the zip that I wasn't even aware should be there. Cypress need better naming of the files downloaded from them.